# LifecycleException in ProjectForge

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, forge

I've installed `ProjectForge` successfully but after some time tomcat starts pausing I found out the following under `logs`. I'm using **XAMPP**.
I assumed it was due to port conflict I have changed the port but I need to know the root cause.

```
     Nov 17, 2014 5:17:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext
     log SEVERE: FAIL - Application at context path /ProjectForge could not
     be started org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: An invalid
     Lifecycle transition was attempted ([before_start]) for component
     [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/ProjectForge]]
     in state [STOPPING]    at
     org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.invalidTransition(LifecycleBase.java:409)
        at
     org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:144)
        at
     org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1256)
        at
     org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:714)
        at
     org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:219)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)     at
     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)   at
     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at
     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at
     org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:212)
        at
     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at
     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at
     org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
        at
     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at
     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at
     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at
     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at
     org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:611)
        at
     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at
     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at
     org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
        at
     org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at
     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at
     org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
        at
     org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at
     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
        at
     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at
     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found the cause of the issues. There are bugs with services provided by ProjectForge. When ever those services are called it ends up throwing error.